# How to export Router instance in Vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm creating a Router instance in order to implement a routing system in my app. So, I'm doing it in such a way:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
  ]
})
```

But I also need to implement a `.beforeEach()` hook on my Router instance. What's the workaround?

I find the way like:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    // ...
});
```

But I guess in my case it won't be correct? What's the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 6):

**Solved:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
  ]
})
```

**Implementing `.beforeEach()` hook on `router` instance:**

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(to.meta.requiresAuth) { 
    if(store.state.session.authenticated) { 
        next();
    }
    else {
        next('/admin/login');
    }
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
});
```

**Exporting the instance:**

```
export default router;
```